# How to apply a namespace to the tf topic?

Tags: moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to set up two instances of the same robot arm. Both are supposed to be controlled by their own MoveIt move_group. I quickly managed to run all relevant nodes within a namespace per arm. However, the topic `/tf` remains outside of both namespaces. I suspect that is the reason, why my move_group ends up controlling both arms at the same time.

I came across `tf_prefix` (http://wiki.ros.org/geometry/CoordinateFrameConventions) which sounds like it would do exactly what I need. However, I could not figure out how to use it. Setting it as a ros param didn't do anything. Is that a MoveIt related issue?

Below see the rqt_graph of my current situation. You can clearly see the box for `/tf` outside of the `/arm1` namespace.
[image: image description]

How can I resolve this?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351740/how-to-apply-a-namespace-to-the-tf-topic?/) by [Saduras](https://answers.ros.org/users/50318/saduras/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2020-05-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ganach9](https://answers.ros.org/users/54548/ganach9/) on 2020-05-07**:
I would run the `rosrun tf view_frames` command and look at the pdf to check how everything is hooked up in your transform tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks Gancha9 the command `rosrun tf view_frames` helped me to understand the tf situation better. It turns out that `tf_prefix` actually worked the way I used it (see frames below). I suppose that solves the question I asked and my actual issue is caused by something else.

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [Saduras](https://answers.ros.org/users/50318/saduras/) with karma: 36 on 2020-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0